# Reference for a proof of this lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm looking for a detailed proof of this lemma, because I can't understand the geometry behind the one I have on my notes.

**Notation:**

1. $C$ is an algebraically closed fields of characteristics zero;
2. $\mathcal{R}(W)$ is the ring of regular functions on $W$.

> **Lemma** Let $V$ be an algebraic subset of $C^n$, let $h$ be a polynomial in $C[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ such that $V \not\subset \mathcal{V}(h)$ and let $W$ be the Zariski locally closed subset of $C^n$ defined by $W:=V \setminus \mathcal{V}(h)$.
>   Then, for each $f \in \mathcal{R}(W)$, there exists a nonnegative integer $s$ depending on $f$ such that the function 
>   $$h^s \cdot f : W \to C$$
>   defined by $(h^s \cdot f)(x)=(h(x))^s\cdot f(x)$ for each $x \in W$ is polynomial (i.e. belongs to $C[W]$).

My idea is that, roughly speaking, at a certain $s$, $h^s$ contains all the denominator of $f$. But, I can't see over this observation.

In the proof I have, it is used some ideals:
$$ \Delta_f := \{ Q \in C[X_1, \ldots, X_n] : Q_W \cdot f \in C[W]\} \qquad \Delta_f^* := \mathcal{I}(V)+\Delta_f$$
where $Q_W$ is the restriction of $Q$ on $W$, if it can be useful.